# MD5: Why am I getting different results for the same string?

Tags: python, md5, hashlib

I expected the following code to return the same result in each case since the string values are the same but instead got a different result each time. What can I do (if anything) to address this?

```
import hashlib

a = 'some text'
b = 'some text'
hashA = hashlib.md5(b'{a}').hexdigest()[:8]
hashB = hashlib.md5(b'{b}').hexdigest()[:8]
hashT = hashlib.md5(b'some text').hexdigest()[:8]

print(hashT) # 552e21cd
print(hashA) # e78fce13
print(hashB) # 09b94c63
print (a==b) # True
```

Comment: Try `print(b'{a}'==b'{b}')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the prefix is f for formatted strings. a, b and 'some text' are different.

Comment: This worked...
hashA = hashlib.md5(a.encode()).hexdigest()[:8]
hashB = hashlib.md5(b.encode()).hexdigest()[:8]
hashT = hashlib.md5('some text'.encode()).hexdigest()[:8]